# What software can be used to play PC games using a smartphone-based VR headset?

Tags: windows, android, vr

I have an android smartphone and one of the cardboard VR headsets based on Google's Cardboard. What software can be used to play VR supporting games on my PC and stream the picture to the phone headset?

I couldn't find anything on the android's marketplace for this, just its own games. What I found was some way of streaming video to phone using remote control software like Teamviewer and there is no definite support for head tracking (moving cursor when looking around). [Link1](http://www.instructables.com/id/Stream-PC-Desktop-to-Phone-for-Virtual-Reality-Now/), [Link2](http://gizmodo.com/notculus-rift-how-i-hacked-together-my-own-serious-vr-1688354373). Those articles are about one year old. Are there better ways than that now?

I'm interested in both complete solutions and works in progress.

Answer (score 2):

[Trinus VR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loxai.trinus.full&hl=en) and [VR Streamer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swatterco.vrstreamer&hl=en) both do what you want.

Comment: Reviews are mixed for both, for what it's worth.